# Is it possible voltage without current and opposite

Tags: voltage, current, ohms-law

I got really surprised by seeing this possibilities from a power, energy calibrator is it really injecting it by violating the laws what we use in practice? See the photos? If anyone knows it please explain it for me.

Current with zero potential difference?

[image: 4Amp,0Volt]

[image: 100mA,0Volt]

Comment: I think you will find all answers to this display in the manual of this calibrator. Please read it! Then show us the circuit it is used with and then you have some chance to get answers.

Comment: Have you ever heard of something called rounding ?

Comment: I dont have a manual of this device and this machine is used by a calibration agency while calibrating our lab equipment

Answer (score 6):

What is the Voltage and current in these two circuits?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frdHkk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The current source driving a short circuit, 0 Ohm, will have 0 V.
The voltage source driving an open circuit, ∞ Ohm, will have 0 A.

Comment: Jeroen3 - you have just used a SYMBOL for the current source. However, do you realize that in our daily electronic practice all our devices we call "current source" are - in fact - voltage sources with a large source resistance? Hence - NO CURRENT without a driving voltage.

Answer (score 3):

a) It doesn't look like it's plugged into anything on the output.

b) That's almost certainly a current *limit*, not measured current.

c) One of those numbers is "-0.46C", so either your lab is *very cold* or the display numbers are unrelated to reality.

Comment: i think it is the mechines internal temperature not ambient temperature

Answer (score 3):

Voltage without current is easy:  There is voltage without current in every unopened package of batteries.

Current without voltage is tricker, but it can be done.  There is current without voltage in every [superconducting magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnet) (e.g., in an MRI magnet).

Comment: this instrument is a calibrator and it produces the v or i at different power factor ,and i dont think there is a superconducting magnet which needs to maintain special atmosphere to make a super conducting magnet

Comment: @Eng.JamshidAlRahman, There's more than one part to your question.  I was answering the "what is possible" part of the question, but see also pjc50's answer, which addresses the "what does this display mean?" part of your question.